# Another regex help for not matching word

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

What I need is to find in code all methods that fetch some entity (A,B,C,D,E..) with invocation like (findBy, fetchUnique.. etc) but don't clear the session, so all code preceded by findBy, fetchUnique and not clearing the session.

So I have this regex as below :

```
\w*(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I).*(?=\.findBy)((?s)(?!\.clear\())
```

And it don't work, any suggestions are welcome.

Update : So adding more details as requested

Lets say I have a method below :

```
public Long test(){
   A a = dao.findByKey(key);
   ....//use a here
   ....
   ....
   return xyz;
}
```

This should match because object a is not cleared by calling dao.clear(a) but below method should not match

```
public Long test(){
   A a = dao.findByKey(key);
   ....//use a here
   ....
   ....
   dao.clear(a);
   return xyz;
}
```

because here a is cleared from session.

Comment: Please show us sample input and what you want to match.

Comment: This won't fix your regex, but since we don't know yet what is the expected input/output, just a small improvement: `A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I` can be replaced by `[A-I]`, which is shorter.

Comment: Thanks for reply but A, B,C etc are symbolic here not alphabet, I am not writing exact code, they are representing entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
\w*(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I).*(?=\.findBy)(?!(?s).*\.clear\()
                                           ||<= here's the diff
```

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA3wV3/1)

Comment: It does work only on a single method given as input at a time.